# Necesito mostrar datos de una BD MYSQL, pero con un rango de fecha de 2 meses

Tags: php, mysql

Chicos, tengo una consulta en la que tal vez me puedan ayudar, resulta que tengo una query en mysql para mostrar un listado de cursos junto con sus datos de una BD, y estos los muestro en un select,

```
<select name="lista_fechas" id="lista_fechas" class="form-control" >
                    <option selected='true'>Elija un curso</option>
                    <?php
                     //   $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'capacitaciones');
                        $con->set_charset("utf8"); 
                        $query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 
                      cursos.nombre_curso, 
                      cursos.id_curso, 
                      cursos.id_relator,
                      DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS Fechas_Cursos,
                      jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,
                      jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
                      jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada, 
                      cursos.id_relator, 
                      cursos.descripcion, 
                      cursos.vacantes, 
                      cursos.ubicacion
                      FROM cursos
                      INNER JOIN jornadas_curso ON jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
                      AND fechas_curso < NOW( ) 
                      GROUP BY nombre_curso
                      ORDER BY fechas_curso ASC
                         ");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_curso'].'">'.$valores['Fechas_Cursos'].' / '.$valores['nombre_curso'].'</option>';                       
                        } 

                       ?>
                  </select>
```

Esto lo tengo para llamar a un AJAX para validar asistencia de alumnos, sin embargo, en algún momento se va a llenar con lista de cursos ya validados, por lo que necesito mostrar cursos en un rango de 2 meses, ¿Como puedo modificar la query para que esto ocurra?,

Saludos y muchas gracias,

Comment: que tipo de dato es tu campo fecha?

Comment: Disculpa la demora, es un varchar